# Centering a slash (not) over a (mathematical) glyph?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, lengths

My aim is to construct a relational symbol which is graphically equivalent the standard infinity sign (coded by`\infty`) crossed exactly in the middle of it. Yet I am not able to overcome something. To be more precise:

[image: sample sentence]

I would like to have slash sign moved exactly to the middle position of the infinity sign. The above was defined in the following way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\length}
\settowidth{\length}{$\infty$}
\newcommand\ninfty{\mathrel{\infty\hspace{-0.5\length/}}} 

$\ninfty$ is not what I am aiming at.

\end{document}
```

So as you can see my idea was to define the length equal to the length of the infinity sign and then place slash sigh it halfway through it. As it can be seen above it was rather please quarter-way (backwards).

Could you please explain what I did wrong and how can I exactly determine the middle point (in terms of width) of a given mathematical glyph? Or a glyph in general?

Comment: actually you did locate the middle but then you aligned the left edge of `/` to the middle of `\infty` you just want to backspace by half the difference between the width of \infty and the witdh of /

Comment: You mean by half the sum of the width of \infty and the width of /?

Comment: oh yes well I meant (but didn't write) padding has to be half the difference on each side, so back space has to be that plus the with of / which comes to what you say:-)

Comment: :) Thanks for the hint. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}
\begin{document}

$\centernot{\infty}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some manual adjusting can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}
\begin{document}

$\centernot{\mkern-0.35mu\infty}\mkern-0.35mu$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finding the *exact* geometric center is not really easy, because it depends on the side bearings of the symbol. Here's a picture showing them

[image]

Also the slash has side bearings, so it's a question of balancing them.

Of course, when you're satisfied with the positioning, you can define

```
\newcommand{\cinfty}{\mathrel{\centernot{\mkern-0.35mu\infty}\mkern-0.35mu}}
```

A different version that uses the slash rather than `\not` (and my favorite tool `\ooalign`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cinfty}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\do@cinfty\relax}}
\newcommand{\do@cinfty}[2]{%
  \vphantom{/}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1/$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\infty$}%
}
\begin{document}

$A\cinfty B_{\cinfty}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More than I would venture to expect :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$\stackon[0pt]{\infty}{/}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the version that is a `\mathrel` and  scales with the math style,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\def\notinfty{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \ThisStyle{\stackon[0pt]{\SavedStyle\infty}{\SavedStyle/}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
$A \notinfty B ~\scriptstyle A\notinfty B ~\scriptscriptstyle A \notinfty B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`\not` is usually optimized for the equals sign. Package `centernot` takes care of the horizontal centering. `\infty` is wider than the equals sign, see egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226017/16967).

The equals sign is vertically centered around the math axis and `\not` usually follows this symmetry. The symbol `\infty`, however, just sits on the base line (Computer Modern fonts, `cmsy10`). Since it seems used with a different meaning as relational symbol, it might be allowed to vertically center it.

The following example centers `\infty` as `\vinfty` vertically around the math axis and uses package `centernot` for the horizontal centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for environment "gather*"

\usepackage{centernot}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\vinfty}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@vinfty{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@vinfty}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{$#1\infty\m@th$}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\notvinfty}{%
  \centernot\vinfty
}

\begin{document}
\centering

{\scriptsize Vertically centered (\texttt{\textbackslash vinfty})}
\begin{gather*}
  a \vinfty b \notvinfty c
\\
  \scriptstyle a \vinfty b \notvinfty c
\\
  \scriptscriptstyle a \vinfty b \notvinfty c
\end{gather*}
%
{\scriptsize Not vertically centered (\texttt{\textbackslash infty})}
\begin{gather*}
  a \mathrel{\infty} b \centernot\infty c
\\
  \scriptstyle a \mathrel{\infty} b \centernot\infty c
\\
  \scriptscriptstyle a \mathrel{\infty} b \centernot\infty c
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]